# surprise.dataset is not a package

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to execute this code

```
import surprise.dataset

file = 'ml-100k/u.data'

col = 'user item rating timestamp'

reader = surprise.dataset.Reader(line_format = col, sep = '\t')
data = surprise.dataset.Dataset.load_from_file(file, reader = reader)

data.split(n_folds = 5)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/prueba2/surprise.py", line 1, in <module>
    import surprise.dataset
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/prueba2/surprise.py", line 1, in <module>
    import surprise.dataset
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprise.dataset'; 'surprise' is not a package
```

But surprise is installed. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a submodule, instead of doing:

```
import surprise.dataset
```

do:

```
from surprise import dataset
```

then in the rest of the code, reference it as `dataset` instead of `surprise.dataset` (i.e. replace `surprise.dataset.Reader` with `dataset.Reader`). If you don’t want to update the rest of your code, you can also just import the whole surprise module instead with:

```
import surprise
```

Comment: with `from surprise import dataset` I get this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset` ,It doesn't found dataset  ,but  surprise its found

Comment: hmm - you sure that the module is called dataset, it may have changed with a different version of Python